# LD_LIBRARY_PATH: Does only work when startup call is also on same line

Tags: linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I can start my program with the following command in the makefile:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(CUDAHOME)/lib64:$(LIBHOME)/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib mpiloader -np 2 ./program
```

When I switch to a two-line version of the same command (as anybody seems to do it)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(CUDAHOME)/lib64:$(LIBHOME)/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib 
mpiloader -np 2 ./program
```

the libraries in boost are no longer found:

```
./program: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As far as I understand, the one and the two line version of the startup code should do exactly the same. What's then wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default every recipe line in a Makefile invokes a new shell instance, so your `export` is only valid up until when the first line finishes executing.

With GNU make you can change this behaviour by defining the [`.ONESHELL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html#One-Shell) special target:

```
.ONESHELL:
all:
    @export foo=bar
    @echo $$foo
```

outputs

```
bar
```